# How to get a template to render with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js

I'm busy building a platform for games you have completed. I do this using the Giantbomb API.

The following code is me testing out the API. I want to give back a random game using the user's input. So if a user searched for Mario, he could get back any Mario game released.

I can't seem to render a template. I can get of loads of information from the API but I only need the name of the game, it's platform and it's release date.

I am new to Backbone.js so I don't know what is wrong.

**Main view**

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el:$('body'),
 game_template: _.template($("#gametemplate").html()),
 url: url = "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[KEY]&format=json",
 events:{
     "keypress input":"findGames"
},

findGames:function(e){ 
  if(e.which == 13){
  self = this;
  query = $(".searchfield").val()
  url = url +"&query="+ query;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var games = data.results
    var game = games[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
    var content = self.game_template({});
    self.$el.append(content);
    $('.main-game').css("display", "block");
    });
  }
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/template" id="gametemplate">
<ul>
  <li><%= name %></
  <li><%= original_release_date %></li>
</ul>
```

Giantbomb API docs http://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation#toc-0-38

I am really clueless.

Comment: url: url = "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[KEY]&format=json", Why not just url:"http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[KEY]&format=json"

Comment: Well in the findGames function I am asking for the entire URL and if I remove either url: or url = I get errors in both the router and the view.

Comment: you can keep the url: just remove url =

Comment: If the code you submitted is an exact copy from yours I think that you have created the 'findGames' function outside the view scope. It should not be getting called on the "keypress input" event.